# nginx permission denied error on alpine drupal 8 docker image

Tags: php, nginx, drupal

We have created a container from this image: https://github.com/bytepark/alpine-drupal8 and connected our drupal 8 site. It seems to load just fine, but when we go to add a new field to a content-type, it fails with no error in the page. Checking /var/log/nginx/error.log I see:

> 2016/09/16 20:58:11 [crit] 13685#13685: *26 open()
>   "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi/7/00/0000000007" failed (13: Permission
>   denied) while reading upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: _, request:
>   "POST
>   /admin/structure/views/ajax/add-handler/content/page_1/field?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "x.x.x.x:8080", referrer:
>   "http://x.x.x.x:8080/admin/structure/views/view/content"

I have tried setting permissions to 777 on /var/lib/nginx and subfolders but that has no effect:

```
root@:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls -l /var/lib/nginx/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Sep 16 20:11 html
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Aug 24 13:27 logs -> /var/log/nginx
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Aug 24 13:27 modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            10 Aug 24 13:27 run -> /run/nginx
drwxrwxrwx    6 nginx    nginx         4096 Sep 16 20:04 tmp

root@:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls -l /var/lib/nginx/tmp
total 16
drwxrwxrwx    2 nginx    nginx         4096 Sep 16 20:04 fastcgi
drwxrwxrwx    2 nginx    nginx         4096 Sep 16 20:04 proxy
drwxrwxrwx    2 nginx    nginx         4096 Sep 16 20:04 scgi
drwxrwxrwx    2 nginx    nginx         4096 Sep 16 20:04 uwsgi
```

I've tried lots of different solutions from google but nothing seems to make any difference, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: may be it can help you http://serverfault.com/a/501264

Comment: I have been trying all of the proposed solutions but none of them seem to have any effect unfortunately